# Determining which monitors/displays/screens are attached

Tags: .net, multiple-monitors

In the windows desktop properties all the displays are shown and are indicated to be active or inactive. My graphics card has a monitor connected to the dvi port but not the vga and this is correctly determined (i.e. one of the displays is labelled inactive). I also have a usb displaylink lcd which is also detected.

Using system.windows.forms.screen.allscreens I am able to enumerate all the possible displays (in this case, 3) on my system but I am unable to determine which ones are active (i.e. actually have a device connected to them). Is this possible in .net?

None of the properties of system.windows.forms.screen seem to have this information.

**EDIT**: Noted that my question is actually a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090052/number-of-physical-monitors-attached-to-a-windows-machine) but I only found it after Hans Passant directed me to looking at WMI.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Number of physical monitors attached to a Windows machine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090052/number-of-physical-monitors-attached-to-a-windows-machine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it cannot see disabled screens.  You'd have to use a low-level hardware query, the kind that are supported by WMI and the System.Management class.  I'd guess at Win32_VideoController, Availability member.  Use the [WMI Code Creator tool](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=2cc30a64-ea15-4661-8da4-55bbc145c30e&displaylang=en) to experiment with the query and get the code you want to use in your program.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As noted in my edit to the question it has helped me to find a duplicate question and set of answers that should help with what I want. The question never appeared despite all the searching I did.